# python kmedoids - calculating new medoid centers more efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I'm following an excellent medium article: https://towardsdatascience.com/k-medoids-clustering-on-iris-data-set-1931bf781e05 to implement kmedoids from scratch.  There is a place in the code where each pixel's distance to the medoid centers is calculated and it is VERY slow. It has numpy.linalg.norm inside a loop. Is there a way to optimize this with numpy.linalg.norm or with numpy broadcasting or scipy.spatial.distance.cdist and np.argmin to do the same thing?

```
###helper function here###
def compute_d_p(X, medoids, p):
    m = len(X)
    medoids_shape = medoids.shape
    # If a 1-D array is provided, 
    # it will be reshaped to a single row 2-D array
    if len(medoids_shape) == 1: 
        medoids = medoids.reshape((1,len(medoids)))
    k = len(medoids)

    S = np.empty((m, k))

    for i in range(m):
        d_i = np.linalg.norm(X[i, :] - medoids, ord=p, axis=1)
        S[i, :] = d_i**p

    return S
```

this is where the slowdown occurs

```
        for datap in cluster_points:
            new_medoid = datap
            new_dissimilarity= np.sum(compute_d_p(X, datap, p))

            if new_dissimilarity < avg_dissimilarity :
                avg_dissimilarity = new_dissimilarity

                out_medoids[i] = datap
```

Full code below. All credits to the article author.

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# Dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = pd.DataFrame(iris.data,columns = iris.feature_names)

target = iris.target_names
labels = iris.target

#Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(data), columns=data.columns)

#PCA Transformation
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(data)
PCAdf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2','principal component 3'])

datapoints = PCAdf.values
m, f = datapoints.shape
k = 3

def init_medoids(X, k):
    from numpy.random import choice
    from numpy.random import seed

    seed(1)
    samples = choice(len(X), size=k, replace=False)
    return X[samples, :]

medoids_initial = init_medoids(datapoints, 3)

def compute_d_p(X, medoids, p):
    m = len(X)
    medoids_shape = medoids.shape
    # If a 1-D array is provided, 
    # it will be reshaped to a single row 2-D array
    if len(medoids_shape) == 1: 
        medoids = medoids.reshape((1,len(medoids)))
    k = len(medoids)

    S = np.empty((m, k))

    for i in range(m):
        d_i = np.linalg.norm(X[i, :] - medoids, ord=p, axis=1)
        S[i, :] = d_i**p

    return S

S = compute_d_p(datapoints, medoids_initial, 2)


def assign_labels(S):
    return np.argmin(S, axis=1)

labels = assign_labels(S)

def update_medoids(X, medoids, p):

    S = compute_d_p(points, medoids, p)
    labels = assign_labels(S)

    out_medoids = medoids

    for i in set(labels):

        avg_dissimilarity = np.sum(compute_d_p(points, medoids[i], p))

        cluster_points = points[labels == i]

        for datap in cluster_points:
            new_medoid = datap
            new_dissimilarity= np.sum(compute_d_p(points, datap, p))

            if new_dissimilarity < avg_dissimilarity :
                avg_dissimilarity = new_dissimilarity

                out_medoids[i] = datap

    return out_medoids

def has_converged(old_medoids, medoids):
    return set([tuple(x) for x in old_medoids]) == set([tuple(x) for x in medoids])

#Full algorithm
def kmedoids(X, k, p, starting_medoids=None, max_steps=np.inf):
    if starting_medoids is None:
        medoids = init_medoids(X, k)
    else:
        medoids = starting_medoids

    converged = False
    labels = np.zeros(len(X))
    i = 1
    while (not converged) and (i <= max_steps):
        old_medoids = medoids.copy()

        S = compute_d_p(X, medoids, p)

        labels = assign_labels(S)

        medoids = update_medoids(X, medoids, p)

        converged = has_converged(old_medoids, medoids)
        i += 1
    return (medoids,labels)

results = kmedoids(datapoints, 3, 2)
final_medoids = results[0]
data['clusters'] = results[1]
```

Comment: @senderle edited to put the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good chance numpy's broadcasting capabilities will help. Getting broadcasting to work in 3+ dimensions is a bit tricky, and I usually have to resort to a bit of trial and error to get the details right.

The use of `linalg.norm` here compounds things further, because my version of the code won't give identical results to `linalg.norm` for all inputs. But I believe it will give identical results for all *relevant* inputs in this case.

I've added some comments to the code to explain the thinking behind certain details.

```
def compute_d_p_broadcasted(X, medoids, p):

    # If a 1-D array is provided, 
    # it will be reshaped to a single row 2-D array

    if len(medoids.shape) == 1: 
        medoids = medoids.reshape((1,len(medoids)))

    # In general, broadcasting n-dim arrays requires that the last
    # dim of the first array be a singleton dimension, and that the
    # first dim of the second array be a singleton dimension. We can
    # quickly accomplish that by slicing with `None` in the appropriate
    # places. (`np.newaxis` is a slightly more self-documenting way
    # of spelling `None`, but I rarely bother.)

    # In this case, the shapes of the other two dimensions also
    # have to align in the same way you'd expect for a dot product.
    # So we pass `medoids.T`.

    diff = np.abs(X[:, :, None] - medoids.T[None, :, :])

    # The last tricky bit is to figure out which axis to sum. Right
    # now, the array is a 3-dimensional array, with the first 
    # dimension corresponding to the rows of `X` and the last 
    # dimension corresponding to the columns of `medoids.T`. 
    # The middle dimension corresponds to the underlying dimensionality
    # of the space; that's what we want to sum for a sum of squares.
    # (Or sum of cubes for L3 norm, etc.)

    return (diff ** p).sum(axis=1)

def compute_d_p(X, medoids, p):
    m = len(X)
    medoids_shape = medoids.shape
    # If a 1-D array is provided, 
    # it will be reshaped to a single row 2-D array
    if len(medoids_shape) == 1: 
        medoids = medoids.reshape((1,len(medoids)))
    k = len(medoids)
    S = np.empty((m, k))
    for i in range(m):
        d_i = np.linalg.norm(X[i, :] - medoids, ord=p, axis=1)
        S[i, :] = d_i**p
    return S

# A couple of simple tests:
X = np.array([[ 1.0,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6],
              [ 7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12]])

medoids = X[[0, 2], :]

np.allclose(compute_d_p(X, medoids, 2), 
            compute_d_p_broadcasted(X, medoids, 2))
# Returns True
np.allclose(compute_d_p(X, medoids, 3),
            compute_d_p_broadcasted(X, medoids, 3))
# Returns True
```

Of course, these tests don't tell whether this actually gives a significant speedup. You'll have to check that yourself for the relevant use-case. But I suspect it will at least help.

Comment: this definitely helps.  to do this on small images is not fast, but the code will run (takes a few mins for image compression)